# Not receiving mail from contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a contact form setup and I am using gmail. However I am not receiving any mail. I am getting the flash alert that the message sent, however looking in the log it doesn't appear that the email is being created.

Can someone take a look and assist me?

contact_mailer.rb:

```
  default :from => "no-reply@domain.com"

    def new_contact(contat)
      @contact = message
    end
  end
```

development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'mygmail@gmail.com',
    password:             'password',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
end
```

Contacts controller:

```
   def create
      @contact = Contact.new(params[:message])
      if @contact.valid?
        ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
```

Contact model:

```
  def initialize(attributes={})
      attributes && attributes.each do |name, value|
        send("#{name}=", value) if respond_to? name.to_sym 
      end
    end
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 15:59:35 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WN19FGciesn2QUiaMtxv4Lwo48tRTkFBSud7OPGRTts=", "contact"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "content"=>"This is a bot."}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'Mqy5_1kyb4hAsrmB9Q0fug' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 15:59:35 -0400
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'Mqy5_1kyb4hAsrmB9Q0fug' LIMIT 1
  Rendered searches/_new.html.erb (5.5ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (8.6ms)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `conversations` INNER JOIN `notifications` ON `notifications`.`conversation_id` = `conversations`.`id` AND `notifications`.`type` IN ('Message') INNER JOIN `receipts` ON `receipts`.`notification_id` = `notifications`.`id` WHERE `notifications`.`type` = 'Message' AND `receipts`.`mailbox_type` = 'inbox' AND `receipts`.`trashed` = 0 AND `receipts`.`deleted` = 0 AND `receipts`.`receiver_id` = 2 AND `receipts`.`receiver_type` = 'User' AND `receipts`.`is_read` = 0
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 78.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development mails aren't delivered by default, add to `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Edit: didn't notice, your mailer method doesn't use `mail` method, does it? Shouldn't it be something like:

mail(to: @contact, subject: 'My awesome mail)

Comment: I added what you recommended and the mail is not being delivered still. I restarted server also to note.

Comment: Thank you. I needed the `mail` method and to add a view for it. Now I just have to fix the `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted` error. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication turned on? This may cause that issue AFAIK.

Comment: So try loggin in as 'normal' user (in browser), maybe gmail turned on some security check? Gmail sometimes does that and gives random errors.